# Getting "The file couldn’t be opened because there is no such file" error from FileManager even though it's actually opened

Tags: ios, swift, plist, nsfilemanager

I'm retrieving a `plist` file, updating it, and writing it to disk.

**1) Retrieval**

```swift
func pListURL() -> URL? {
     guard let result = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("somePlist.plist") else { return nil }
     return result
 }
```

**2) Update**

```swift
var data: [String: Int] = [:]
if let url = pListURL() {
    do {
        let dataContent = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        if let dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: dataContent, format: nil) as? [String: Int] {
            data = dict
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

// update code
```

**3) Write**

```swift
if let path = pListURL() {
    do {
        let plistData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: data, format: .xml, options: 0)
        try plistData.write(to: path)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The odd thing is I get an error that says:

> The file “somePlist.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

even though when I check the `plist`, it's actually properly created and updated as it should be. As far as I know, the `create` parameter of [FileManager.default.url(for:in:appropriateFor:create: )](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url) ensures that it "creates the directory if it does not already exist", which means `somePlist.plist` is created if `plist` doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know, the create parameter of FileManager.default.url(for:in:appropriateFor:create: ) ensures that it "creates the directory if it does not already exist", which means somePlist.plist is created if plist doesn't exist already.

No, it means the *directory* is created but the *file* is **not** created.

In the *update* part ignore the `couldn’t be opened` error and write the (new) data to disk or check if the file exists with `fileExists(atPath`.

And you can declare the return value in `pListURL` as non-optional. It's guaranteed that the folder `Documents` exists

```
func pListURL() -> URL {
     return try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("somePlist.plist")
}
```

---

Update:

These are reliable versions of `update` and `write`

```
func update(dictionary: [String:Int]) {
    let url = pListURL()
    guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) else { write(dictionary: dictionary); return }
    do {
        let dataContent = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        if var dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: dataContent, format: nil) as? [String: Int] {
            for (key, value) in dictionary {
                dict.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
            }
            write(dictionary: dict)
        } else {
            write(dictionary: dictionary)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func write(dictionary: [String:Int]) {
    let url = pListURL()
    do {
        let plistData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: dictionary, format: .xml, options: 0)
        try plistData.write(to: url)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "ignore the couldn’t be opened error", do you mean placing the the code for writing to disk within `catch`?

Comment: Yes, but you need to catch the specific `couldn’t be opened` error. I'd prefer to check if the file exists before the `do` block.

Comment: I'd be checking if the file exists within the `pListURL()` function during the Retrieval process, correct?

Comment: Actually that's not useful because the URL must be returned even if the file doesn't exist. Or return only the base documents folder URL.

Comment: I don't think the `URL` is needed if the file doesn't already exist. A new file with a new `URL` would be created during the Write process.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. Could you explain the reason why `It's guaranteed that the folder Documents exists`?

Comment: The folder Documents is created in the application container during the app installation process.